# Change the customized ListView.Items after each build

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, enums, design-time

I create a customized `ListView` that inherited from standard `ListView` in `.NET` to show an `enum` values as its `Items`(`WinForms` project):

```
public class ScrapGroupsListView : ListView
{
    public event EventHandler SelectedColorChanged;

    private ScrapGroup _selectedGroup = ScrapGroup.None;

    [DefaultValue(ScrapGroup.None)]
    public ScrapGroup SelectedScrapGroup
    {
        get { return _selectedGroup; }
        set
        {
            if (_selectedGroup != value)
            {
                _selectedGroup = value;
                foreach (ListViewItem item in this.Items)
                {
                    if (item != null)
                    {
                        if (item.Tag != null)
                        {
                            var itemColor = (ScrapGroup)item.Tag;
                            if (itemColor == ScrapGroup.None) 
                                item.Checked = value == ScrapGroup.None;
                            else
                                item.Checked = value.HasFlag(itemColor);
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (SelectedColorChanged != null) 
                   SelectedColorChanged.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }

    public ScrapGroupsListView()
    {
        this.Items.Clear();
        this.CheckBoxes = true;
        this.HeaderStyle = ColumnHeaderStyle.None;
        this.View = View.List;

        foreach (var value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(ScrapGroup)).Cast<ScrapGroup>())
        {
            this.Items.Add(new ListViewItem()
            {
                Name = value.ToString(),
                Text = value.ToString(),
                Tag = value,
            });
        }
    }

    protected override void OnItemChecked(ItemCheckedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnItemChecked(e);

        var checkedScrapGroup = (ScrapGroup)e.Item.Tag;

        if (e.Item.Checked)
            if (checkedScrapGroup == ScrapGroup.None)
                SelectedScrapGroup = ScrapGroup.None;
            else
                SelectedScrapGroup |= checkedScrapGroup;
        else
            SelectedScrapGroup &= ~checkedScrapGroup;
    }
}
```

`ScrapGrouop` is my enum:

```
[Flags]
public enum ScrapGroup
{
    None=0,
    M=1,
    E=2,
    N=4,
    H=8
}
```

when I put the `ScrapGroupsListView` to my form, everything is OK and the control has no Items:

[image]

But each time I build my project, the `ScrapGroup` values add to `ScrapGroupsListView.Items` (design-time):

after 1st build:

[image]

after 2nd build:

[image]

and so on.

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of constructor try:

```
protected override void OnCreateControl()
    {
        base.OnCreateControl();

        this.Items.Clear();
        this.CheckBoxes = true;
        this.HeaderStyle = ColumnHeaderStyle.None;
        this.View = View.List;

        foreach (var value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(ScrapGroup)).Cast<ScrapGroup>())
        {
            this.Items.Add(new ListViewItem()
            {
                Name = value.ToString(),
                Text = value.ToString(),
                Tag = value,
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time you open the form in the VS designer it creates this code:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem listViewItem1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem("None");
    System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem listViewItem2 = new System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem("M");
    System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem listViewItem3 = new System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem("E");
    System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem listViewItem4 = new System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem("N");
    System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem listViewItem5 = new System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem("H");
    this.scrapGroupsListView1 = new ScrapGroupsListView();
    // 
    // scrapGroupsListView1
    // 
    this.scrapGroupsListView1.CheckBoxes = true;
    this.scrapGroupsListView1.HeaderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeaderStyle.None;
    listViewItem1.StateImageIndex = 0;
    listViewItem1.Tag = ScrapGroup.None;
    listViewItem2.StateImageIndex = 0;
    listViewItem2.Tag = ScrapGroup.M;
    listViewItem3.StateImageIndex = 0;
    listViewItem3.Tag = ScrapGroup.E;
    listViewItem4.StateImageIndex = 0;
    listViewItem4.Tag = ScrapGroup.N;
    listViewItem5.StateImageIndex = 0;
    listViewItem5.Tag = ScrapGroup.H;
    this.scrapGroupsListView1.Items.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem[] {
    listViewItem1,
    listViewItem2,
    listViewItem3,
    listViewItem4,
    listViewItem5});
```

This is why your items appear two times. First set from the constructor, second set from `InitializeComponent()`.

You can (and should) remove the code from `InitializeComponent()` but opening the form in the designer will screw it up again.

To prevent from this you can move the filling code to a separate method and invoke it from the form.

In your control:

```
public ScrapGroupsListView()
{
    this.CheckBoxes = true;
    this.HeaderStyle = ColumnHeaderStyle.None;
    this.View = View.List;
}

public void Fill()
{
    this.Items.Clear();

    foreach( var value in Enum.GetValues( typeof( ScrapGroup ) ).Cast<ScrapGroup>() )
    {
        this.Items.Add( new ListViewItem()
        {
            Name = value.ToString(),
            Text = value.ToString(),
            Tag = value,
        } );
    }
}
```

In your form:

```
public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    scrapGroupsListView1.Fill();
}
```

As a drawback at this solution you don't see your items in the designer.